Unable to Install Python Wheel on Databricks Community Edition
Just recently I have been unable to install any Python Wheel on Databricks Community Edition - even though I installed the a Python wheel as recently as two days ago. I'm getting the following error:
However, I can install the same Python wheel on my Azure Databricks Instance.
Has there been any changes to Databricks Community Edition preventing the installation of Python Wheels using the method I'm described in the image?


did you try installing via  %pip install path in your notebook?

Hi @GaneshChandrasekaran, thanks for getting in touch. The problem was a global problem. It was eventually fixed by Databricks.
